# Python: asking if two objects are the same class

Tags: python, polymorphism, instance

I have a class Animal and other animals inherit from it (e.q. Sheep, Wolf).
I want to check if two objects are the same class and if so, it should create new object of the same class and if they are not, they are fighting.

```
if x and y same object:
    #create new object
else:
    #fight
```

Is there a better method than `isinstance`?
Because, there will be more animals than just 2 and I think it wouldn't be efficient to do it like this:

```
if isinstance(x, Wolf)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you can simply use

```
if type(x) == type(y):
    fight()
```

Python has a type system that allows you to do exactly that.

EDIT: as Martijn has pointed out, since Types only exist once in every runtime, you can use `is` instead of `==`:

```
if type(x) is type(y):
    fight()
```

Comment: Classes are singletons, so it'd be more efficient to use `type(x) is type(y)`.

Comment: you're right! @MartijnPieters, how comes you always notice when I'm sloppy? ;)

Comment: The *better* option is to delegate this task to the instances directly, where you know the type in the method. `def fight(self, other): if not isinstance(self, Wolf): return NotImplemented`, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'd generally agree, and it feels much more like C++ (which is what I probably like most about it); I'd even go as far as overloading the `+`/`__add__` operator! Also, if you derive all your animals from the same base class, you can simply check `if not isinstance(other, type(self))` and it will work as it should for all animals. In fact, this even feels like I should write a decorator, so that one can define methods that only take arguments of the same type as the containing class!

Answer (score -5):

if obj1==obj2:
pass
else:
#do som

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This comparison is far too strict; the question only asks for the objects to be instances of the same class, not for the objects to `__eq__` each other as is the case for this answer.